# How do I report this error to the "update manager"

Tags: command-line, update-manager, community

How do I solve this error

```
"E:can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_InRelease - fopen (13: Permission denied), 
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."
```

Comment: What is the command you're running? Is this the complete output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this unmet error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322512/what-is-this-unmet-error)